# checkAll by attribute not firing?

Tags: jquery

Im confused why this isnt working and am not able to debug

I have a set of checkboxe's grouped by an attribute value
and have a checkall class at the foot of each group with matching attribute value when i click this i want to toggle the other checkboxs to same state

jquery

```
$(function () {
    $('.checkall').click(function () {
        var myactivemonth=$(this).attr("data-mymonth");
        console.log(myactivemonth);
        var myactivebox="a_"+myactivemonth;
        $('checkbox[data_mymonth=myactivemonth]').attr('checked','checked');
});
```

html

```
<input id="alloInv" class="tip_trigger" type="checkbox" data-mymonth="a_October2012" title="13.94" value="2018441" name="alloInv">
<input id="alloInv" class="tip_trigger" type="checkbox" data-mymonth="a_October2012" title="10.94" value="201845" name="alloInv"> 
<input class="checkall" type="checkbox" data-mymonth="October2012">
```

IT appears all ok but the boxes aren't ticking :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a series of wrong things

1. `checkbox` should be `:checkbox`
2. `data_mymonth` should be `data-mymonth`
3. `myactivebox` needs to be passed dynamically
4. from the code in the question you are missing the final `});`

A couple of improvements as well

1. you should use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` for actual properties of the element. `$(this).data('mymonth');`
2. use `.data()` to retrieve values from `data-` attributes

So

```
$(':checkbox[data-mymonth="' + myactivebox + '"]').prop('checked',true);
```

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/6Nv3N/

---

**Update**

I missed the ***toggle*** part of your question

To handle toggling the checkboxes you need to set the `checked` property to that of the `.checkall` element.

The `.prop()` way ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6Nv3N/8/))

```
$(':checkbox[data-mymonth="' + myactivebox + '"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
```

---

The `.attr()` way

```
$(':checkbox[data-mymonth="' + myactivebox + '"]').attr('checked', this.checked);
```

Comment: Ok sorry for being new to Jquery and a cocoffany of sin's there

2 quick things I tried using prop() but it returned an error prop is not a function ? may be because using jquery 1.4.2 ? or other reason ? 

Once altered back to attr this worked when setting them to checked but wouldnt toggle I altered your fiddle but even that doosnt work, is there a better way to toggle a checkbox with the toggle option and keep the sets in sync ?

Comment: @StevenMoffat, no worries :) Yes `.prop` was added at v1.6 of jquery. Updated answer for toggling the checkboxes..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this did it but im sure theres a neater way to toggle the state of the checkbox ?

```
$(function() {
    $('.checkall').click(function() {
        var myactivemonth = $(this).attr("data-mymonth");
        var mystate = $(this).attr("checked");

            if (mystate==undefined) {mystate=false;};

        console.log(myactivemonth);
        var myactivebox = "a_" + myactivemonth;
        $(':checkbox[data-mymonth="' + myactivebox + '"]').attr('checked',mystate);
    });
});
```

PS updated the jquery squiggle tnow thats a helpfull tool !